How do I create a fov viewport box to show what the camera can see of the minimap?
hey i was trying to create a minimap with 2 cameras (render texture and camera for it)
and now i am trying to create a fov viewport box to show what the camera can see of the minimap
i can't raycast because the game is in space (homeworld kind of game) with no ground. i hope anyone knows how to do this because i am losing my sanity
my code:
void UpdateFOVBox()
{
    // Get main camera properties
    Vector3 cameraPosition = mainCamera.transform.position;
    Quaternion cameraRotation = mainCamera.transform.rotation;
    float distance = -cameraPosition.y;

    float height = distance * Mathf.Tan(mainCamera.fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float width = height * mainCamera.aspect;

    Vector3 upVector = cameraRotation * Vector3.up;
    Vector3 rightVector = cameraRotation * Vector3.right;

    Vector3 topLeft = cameraPosition - rightVector * (width / 2) + upVector * (height / 2);
    Vector3 topRight = cameraPosition + rightVector * (width / 2) + upVector * (height / 2);
    Vector3 bottomLeft = cameraPosition - rightVector * (width / 2) - upVector * (height / 2);
    Vector3 bottomRight = cameraPosition + rightVector * (width / 2) - upVector * (height / 2);

    Vector2 topLeftMinimap = minimapCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(topLeft);
    Vector2 topRightMinimap = minimapCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(topRight);
    Vector2 bottomLeftMinimap = minimapCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(bottomLeft);
    Vector2 bottomRightMinimap = minimapCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(bottomRight);

    float minX = Mathf.Min(topLeftMinimap.x, topRightMinimap.x, bottomLeftMinimap.x, bottomRightMinimap.x) * minimapRect.rect.width;
    float maxX = Mathf.Max(topLeftMinimap.x, topRightMinimap.x, bottomLeftMinimap.x, bottomRightMinimap.x) * minimapRect.rect.width;
    float minY = Mathf.Min(topLeftMinimap.y, topRightMinimap.y, bottomLeftMinimap.y, bottomRightMinimap.y) * minimapRect.rect.height;
    float maxY = Mathf.Max(topLeftMinimap.y, topRightMinimap.y, bottomLeftMinimap.y, bottomRightMinimap.y) * minimapRect.rect.height;

    float boxWidth = maxX - minX;
    float boxHeight = maxY - minY;

    float aspectCorrection = minimapCamera.aspect / mainCamera.aspect;
    boxWidth *= aspectCorrection;

    fovBox.sizeDelta = new Vector2(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    fovBox.anchorMin = new Vector2(minX / minimapRect.rect.width, minY / minimapRect.rect.height);
    fovBox.anchorMax = new Vector2(maxX / minimapRect.rect.width, maxY / minimapRect.rect.height);

    float angle = mainCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y;
    fovBox.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, angle);
}

this doesn't work properly because the fov box doesn't scale with the camera zooming in and out (y position changing) and idk how to get it woring

personally, Id do a raycase in each corner, to ground, and just draw a square based on the 4 corners.  But im not overly understanding what you mean by show what the camera can see of the minimap, its whatever comes out that camera...
